# How can I discover the ip ranges for a particular ISP for roadwarrior vpn whitelisting?

Tags: ip, internet

I have a road warrior who will be based overseas for several months and will be using a particular ISP.  Our VPN is white-listed. Rather than add his IP which changes every few days, is there a way of discovering the whole range for this ISP?  e.g. a list I can view online or a service I can query.

Worst case, I could probably guess it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Available address ranges change frequently, and while whois can provide you with *some* hints, it isn't going to get you close to something you can just fire-and-forget.

IP-based restrictions aren't an effective security tool anyway.  You're far better to implement rate-limiting (to protect against brute-force attacks) and keep your services patched to avoid getting hit by the vuln-of-the-week.

Comment: I would disagree with our comment about IP-base restrictions.  In my opinion it stops whole continents turning up at the doorstep trying to get in.  True, it won't stop the most determined hacker trying to do an extremely difficult but technically possible IP spoof, but then I'm happy to block nearly everyone from attempting that.

Comment: By the way, you could say - I'm the road warrior.  I just wanted to word the question in a way that made sense to SF

Comment: IP *blacklisting* makes sense, in the same way that geographic-oriented fraud detection works for credit cards.  Conversely, your credit card provider doesn't make you list all the shops you might decide to buy from in advance, and neither should you try to enumerate a limited set of IP addresses from which you may wish to connect to your VPN.